# Передача массива при помощи Parcelable Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-parcelable, kotlin-parcelize

возникла следующая проблема: я пытаюсь передать массив при помощи Parcelable из одной activity в другую. 
Задаю дата класс и передаю следующим образом:

```
@Parcelize
data class Gadget ( val gadgetValues: MutableList<Int>) :Parcelable

private fun sendGadget () {
    val gadgetValues = Gadget(mutableListOf(1,2,3))
    val intent = Intent (this, MainActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("extra_Gadget", gadgetValues)
    Log.d("sendGadget", "$gadgetValues")
}
```

и принимаю результат в другой активности:

val itemGadgets = intent.getParcelableExtra("extra_Gadget")

Но в переменную почему то передается null.
В чем я ошибся?

Comment: а в логах есть что-то?

Comment: В логе, представленном выше в gadgetValues находится Gadget(gadgetValues[1,2,3]), а при приеме у itemGadgets значение null

Comment: А `startActivity()` где? Не вижу чтобы интент отправлялся.